# OverflowException in IMongoCollection<T>.UpdateOneAsync although no arithmetic operation is done

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm encountering a `'System.OverflowException' in MongoDB.Bson.dll` (`Additional information: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.`), when calling `UpdateOneAsync` with no idea why:

```
CarSpec spec = GetSpec();
var updateDefinition = Builders<Cars>.Update.Set(c => c.Spec, spec);
IMongoCollection<CarBatch> carsBatch = GetCarsBatch();
var result = await carsBatch.UpdateOneAsync(c => c.Id == car.Id, updateDefinition);
```

These are the important data structures:

```
public class Car {
    public string Id;
    public ServiceVersion CurrentVersion = new ServiceVersion();
    public CarSpec Spec = new CarSpec();
    public List<StatusNotice> StatusNotifications = new List<StatusNotice>();
}

public class CarSpec {
    internal const uint InitialChasisNumber = 1000000000;

    public uint ChasisNumber = InitialChasisNumber;
    public uint DoorsCount;
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't anything related to uint data type? Try to update to int and tell us result.

As you can see on MongoDB documentation, the available BSON Types supported does't include uint32.

Check it here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: I updated the question with correct fields, but you got it anyway... my `CarSpec GetSpec()` returned `ChasisNumber` which is bigger than `2^31`.

Comment: int32 range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and uint range is 0 to 4,294,967,295. In this case, you could use int64, where the range is –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and will work properly for you code. :)